# Setar valor no textarea (TinyMCE) ao clicar na linha da table

Tags: javascript, html5, node.js, bootstrap-4, tinymce

Fala galera, estou precisando de uma ajudinha aqui... 
estou usando o plugin TinyMCE num elemento textarea da minha aplicação Node.JS, queria saber como faço para setar um texto neste elemento, este texto está vindo de um forEach do MySQL onde ao clicar no botão editar da linha da minha tabela faz um set value nos elementos do modal, abaixo trecho referente:

```
<td>
<button class="btn btn-xs btn-warning" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modalEdit" onclick="(function(){

   //Setando o valor nos campos de texto
   document.getElementById('cod_Section9Sub_Alterar').value = '<%= row.cod %>';
   document.getElementById('autor_Section9Sub_Alterar').value = '<%= row.autor %>';
   document.getElementById('titulo_Section9Sub_Alterar').value = '<%= row.titulo %>';
   document.getElementById('artigo_Section9Sub_Alterar').value = '<%= row.artigo %>';//Ajuda aqui

})()">

Editar</button>
</td>
```

E aqui é o trecho do meu elemento textarea que está dentro do modal chamado:

```
<!-- Artigo -->
<div class="row">
 <div class="col-sm-12">
  <div class="form-group">
   <label for="artigo_Section9Sub_Alterar" class="label">Sua postagem</label>
    <textarea class="form-control" name="artigo_Section9Sub_Alterar"
    id="artigo_Section9Sub_Alterar" placeholder="Sua postagem" rows="10 auto"
    required></textarea>
   </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Se eu retiro a linha do set value do textarea tudo funciona perfeitamente, se eu volto este trecho deixa de popular o modal.

Já tentei a opção: `tinymce.get('#artigo_Section9Sub_Alterar').setContent('<%= row.artigo %>');`  e também não rolou.

Comment: Tenta assim: `document.getElementById("artigo_Section9Sub_Alterar_ifr").contentDocument.querySelector("body").innerHTML = "<%= row.artigo %>";`. Dependendo do que vem no `<%= row.artigo %>`, essa não é a forma ideal de se fazer isso.

Comment: Deu certo Sam, porém acrescentando window.parent olha:
window.parent.tinymce.get('artigo_Section9Sub_Alterar').getBody().innerHTML = '<%= row.artigo %>';

Muito obrigado!
Por favor, adicione como resposta na pergunta pra eu poder marcar como solução.

Comment: Legal. Sem o window.parent não funciona?

Comment: não, sem ele não funcionou.

Comment: Só window deve funcionar tb, porque o parent pega a janela pai, e se vc já está na janela pai é redundante usar o parent. Mas dá na mesma no final.

Comment: verdade, só com window deu certo, Sam se puder me ajudar em mais uma dúvida agradeço: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/456168/exibir-texto-do-bd-numa-div-considerando-as-tags-html-contidas-neste-texto

Answer (score 0):

Com ajuda do nosso colega Sam, problema resolvido.

Solução: `window.parent.tinymce.get('artigo_Section9Sub_Alterar').getBody().innerHTML = '<%= row.artigo %>';`