# Exibir texto do BD numa div considerando as tags HTML contidas neste texto

Tags: mysql, html5, node.js

Fala galera, tenho um texto gravado no BD MySql onde, este texto já contém todas as tags de formatação.

Na minha página font-end, eu recebo este texto através de um forEach e passo ele numa div da página, porém, não está refletindo as formatações das tags, as tags estão vindo como texto.

Exemplo do texto contido na tabela 'artigo' do BD:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Aqui está minha div que receberá este conteúdo:

```
<div data-content="html"><%= row.artigo %></div>
```

E aqui como está sendo exibido na página:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Tenta assim: `<%=html_entity_decode(row.artigo) %>`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mude o `<%= row.artigo %>` para `<%- row.artigo %>`

A difernça é que o `<%-` passa os dados exatamente como estão, em seu formato "raw", sem fazer nenhum parse ou encode, e como eles já vem como `html` do banco, vai ser mostrados corretamente na página.

Comment: Obrigado Ricardo, tem razão, deu certo.